# How to dynamically generate RGB colors based on a color scale by values

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a function that creates RGB colors using this color scale based on an array of number values.

I need the feature colors to be from solid Red to Solid Green (including shades) based on value. I am trying to achieve this using a RGB function and a logarithmic function but am having issues figuring it out.

For Example, these features that are different heights should be different shades of green. The solid reds are ok because in this example those values are either negative or zero.
[image: Example]

```js
    const values = [
      4735851.45,
      3478941.36,
      172950126.31,
      -410395.6,
      -8151600.12,
      -178715.98,
      43875532.36,
      1475628.37,
      -14617618.12,
      null,
      1506789.78,
      -3146.7,
      -475341.43,
      66.84,
      51214981.55,
      154389200.99,
      0,
      -4001429.66,
      1087.85,
      -404043.69,
      0,
      6583807.95,
      -206089.9,
      -1838657.73,
      -17765800.61,
      0,
      -2542386.32,
      -1982363.44,
      66382955.45,
      null,
      -1671965.58,
      4735851.45,
      3478941.36,
      172950126.31,
      -410395.6,
      -8151600.12,
      -178715.98,
      43875532.36,
      1475628.37,
      -14617618.12,
      null,
      1506789.78,
      -3146.7,
      -475341.43,
      66.84,
      51214981.55,
      154389200.99,
      0,
      -4001429.66,
      1087.85,
      -404043.69,
      0,
      6583807.95,
      -206089.9,
      -1838657.73,
      -17765800.61,
      0,
      -2542386.32,
      -1982363.44,
      66382955.45,
      null,
      -1671965.58,
      624522.5,
      -15336485.14,
      31493663.15,
      159679.77,
      1291366.47,
      38094.5,
      -2706753.67,
      1376310.97,
      949264.92,
      null,
      321526.02,
      -219.81,
      -1327197.43,
      5.57,
      7888714.79,
      27806820.36,
      0,
      -1833219.77,
      1087.85,
      -292279.72,
      null,
      617306.25,
      -146691.46,
      15860.82,
      -25856737.74,
      null,
      14576.42,
      -113968.38,
      6870613.36,
      null,
      -3310968.31
    ];

    const hsv2rgb = (h, s, v) => {
      let rgb;
      let i;
      let data = [];
      if (s === 0) {
        rgb = [v, v, v];
      } else {
        h /= 60;
        i = Math.floor(h);
        data = [v * (1 - s), v * (1 - s * (h - i)), v * (1 - s * (1 - (h - i)))];
        switch (i) {
          case 0:
            rgb = [v, data[2], data[0]];
            break;
          case 1:
            rgb = [data[1], v, data[0]];
            break;
          case 2:
            rgb = [data[0], v, data[2]];
            break;
          case 3:
            rgb = [data[0], data[1], v];
            break;
          case 4:
            rgb = [data[2], data[0], v];
            break;
          default:
            rgb = [v, data[0], data[1]];
            break;
        }
      }
      return rgb.map((x) => Math.round(x * 255));
    };

    function logslider(position) {
      const minp = 0;
      const maxp = 1000000000;
      const minv = Math.log(10);
      const maxv = Math.log(10000);
      const scale = (maxv - minv) / (maxp - minp);
      return Math.exp(minv + scale * (position - minp))
    }

    console.clear();
    for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      if (values[i]) {
        let rgbResult = [];
        if (Math.sign(values[i]) === 1) {
          const val = logslider(values[i]);
          const h = Math.floor(((100 - val) * 120) / 100);
          const s = Math.abs(val - 50) / 50;
          rgbResult = hsv2rgb(h, s, 1);
        } else rgbResult = [255, 0, 0];
        console.log(rgbResult);
      }
    }
```

Comment: what more focus do I need? How about before the downvote someone actually suggests something that could help me explain it? I am not a expert at asking questions

Comment: Is the color scale fixed, i.e. there will always be 19 shades? Maybe you could just create a simple 2D array of RGB values with corresponding values ranges.

Comment: And as far as I can see, there are two scales. (1) from red to almost white, (2) and from almost white to green. Inside the scales colours can be interpolated. Not exactly universal solution, but I'd prefer to make an array of predefined colours and use the colours from the array instead of a tricky interpolation.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to do this is by interpolating between colors. You can define a linear interpolation function like this:

```js
function lerp(a, b, t) {
  return a + (b - a) * t;
}
```

And use it to interpolate between RGB values like this:

```js
let start = [255, 0, 0];
let end = [0, 255, 0];

function lerpColors(a, b, t) {
  return [
    lerp(a[0], b[0], t),
    lerp(a[1], b[1], t),
    lerp(a[2], b[2], t)
  ]
}
```

And you can modify this simple process to add more colors to the interpolation scale. I built a [node module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/curves) in an attempt to make it easier to construct "curves" and "color curves" like this, there's a live demo of a color curve on the [demo site](http://robertzmay.com/curves-demo/). Its not a great node module, but the code is accessible on GitHub, so maybe you can steal some of the logic I used there.